# How do I modify a RSS feed to combine items

Tags: rss

I've got a feed with over 30 item per day, but all I'm really looking for is a daily (or semi-daily) digest. This way, I'll only get 1-2 items a day. The site itself doesn't offer such a feed. What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Update: I'm looking at [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com). Will post an update if I can get anything to work.

Comment: The easiest? Just look at the feed once (or twice) a day instead of every time it gets updated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **Yahoo Pipes** is definitely the answer to your question http://pipes.yahoo.com/

Answer (score 0):

If a site doesn't provide a digest feed, then there's not much you can do other than check this feed less often. I don't know of any readers that provide this kind of feature.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test but it's a hack off the top of my head.

Something like this http://www.feedmyinbox.com/ + Google Groups. Have FMI send items to the group. Tell the group to send daily updates via email to some blogger site like Wordpress, blogger, or some other post-a-block-of-text-via-email site. Subscribe to resultant feed. This is basically buffering and bundling through emails.